# URL in URL for flashplayer

Tags: php, asp.net, html, flash

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashapplication.swf?plan=plans/images/OBJECT_<%=iID %>_swffile.swf&data=./cgi-bin/dynamicXML.ashx&nextargument=nextvalue" />
<param name="parameter1" value="NULL" />
<param name="parameter2" value="NULL" />
</object>
```

Now i should pass a parameter in cgi-bin/dynamicXML.ashx a parameter in its url, while this is inside the object/embed tag like `cgi-bin/dynamicXML.ashx?objectid=1`

How can I do that ?

Comment: Next time please use the Code button to format your code instead of replacing `<` with `&lt;` and so on, I fixed it now but I may have inadvertently changed something, double check it!

Comment: do you want to get a value for the query string and put it in your <param /> tags?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, I think you want to take a look at flashvars - http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html

That will let you pass parameters from HTML into your Flash Player so you can make the Flash content dynamic based on variables from your PHP or ASP.NET application.

=Ryan ryan@adobe.com